# Facing an error after changing the Google OAuth restricted scope to non-sensitive scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console, google-code

I am trying to integrate my web appication with google OAuth. When i modified the restricted scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) to a non-sensitive scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file). However, after implementing these changes, when attempting to fetch drive files, the response yields an empty files array, despite the existence of files in the drive account. Additionally, no error code is being returned. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

I have executed my code using google OAuth client library but there is no code change based on each different scopes.

Comment: Are you trying to list the drive's files? If yes, the scope `drive.file` does not allow you to do that. Refer to this [document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth) for more information on Google Drive OAuth Scopes.